# What is wrong in my code, why doesn't the thing show, ai chose: __

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking for some help, so while I was creating my rock paper scissors in JavaScript, but I seem to be stuck, I don't know why aiChoice's value isn't getting assigned, I don't know why it doesn't display "Ai Chose: __", here's the code

```
        let playerChoice = null;
        let aiChoice = null;
        let results = null;
        let clicked = false;
        
        
        rock.addEventListener("click", function(){
          playerChoice+=0;
          clicked = true;
          you.textContent = "You chose: rock"
        });
        paper.addEventListener("click", function(){
          playerChoice+=1;
          clicked = true;
          you.textContent = "You chose: paper"
        });
        scissors.addEventListener("click", function(){
          playerChoice+=2;
          clicked = true;
          you.textContent = "You chose: scissors"
        });
        
        
          if(clicked) {
            let var1 = Math.random() * 2;
            aiChoice = Math.round(var1);
          }
        
        switch(aiChoice){
          case 0:
            ai.textContent = "AI Chose: rock";
            break;
          case 1:
            ai.textContent = "AI Chose: paper";
            break;
          case 2:
            ai.textContent = "AI Chose: scissors";
            break;
        }
```

Comment: `playerChoice+=0` doesn't do anything. Adding 0 to a number doesn't change it.

Comment: You need to initialize `playerChoice` to a number, you can't add to `null`.

Comment: You're checking `clicked` when the page first loads, not after the user clicks something. You need to put all the code that compares the user and player choices into a function that you call from the `click` event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

For the AiChoice, an easier way than this would be to have a list with the 3 options ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'] and then choose a random item from the list. For the player, you can have the 3 buttons with the classes rock paper and scissors respectively and then on click of the button, generate the aiChoice as well. Here's the code example :

```js
const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
const scissor = document.querySelector('.scissor');
const playerOptions = [rock,paper,scissor];
const aiOptions = ['rock','paper','scissors'];

playerOptions.forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener('click',function(){
        you.textContent = 'You chose: ${this.innerText}'

        const choiceNo = Math.round(Math.random()*2);
        const aiChoice = aiOptions[choiceNo];
        ai.textContent = 'AI Chose: ${ aiChoice }';
}
```

```html
<div class="options">
    <button class="rock">Rock</button>
    <button class="paper">Paper</button>
    <button class="scissor">Scissors</button>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have made a small change in your code. As we all know, javascript does not wait to run a line of code until the previous line is finished. So once you run your code, it will not wait for the click event to check whether the ***clicked*** variable is true or not. so that's why ***ai.textContent*** is not setting correctly. To overcome that situation, I put the ***AI*** part into a function and call it every time the click event triggers.

```js
                let playerChoice = null;
        let aiChoice = null;
        let results = null;
        let you= {
        textContent: ''
        };
        let ai = {
         textContent: ''
        };
        
        var rock = document.getElementById("rock");
        var paper = document.getElementById("paper");
        var scissors = document.getElementById("scissors");
        var textoutput = document.getElementById("textoutput");
        
        rock.addEventListener("click", function(){
          playerChoice = 0;
          you.textContent = "You chose: rock";
          aiAction();
        });
        paper.addEventListener("click", function(){
          playerChoice = 1;
          you.textContent = "You chose: paper";
          aiAction();
        });
        scissors.addEventListener("click", function(){
          playerChoice = 2;
          you.textContent = "You chose: scissors";
          aiAction();
        });
        
        
        function aiAction(){
            let var1 = Math.random() * 2;
            aiChoice = Math.round(var1);
            switch(aiChoice){
              case 0:
                ai.textContent = "AI Chose: rock";
                break;
              case 1:
                ai.textContent = "AI Chose: paper";
                break;
              case 2:
                ai.textContent = "AI Chose: scissors";
                break;
            }
            
            var output = `${you.textContent} & ${ai.textContent}`;
            textoutput.innerHTML = output;
        }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <div>
    <button id="rock">
      rock
    </button>
    <button id="paper">
      paper
    </button>
    <button id="scissors">
      scissors
    </button>
  </div>
    <p id="textoutput"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```